# pthread_create segmentation fault for file reading

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pthreads

I have a class `Class1` with a method `Class1::Run` that is called sequentially. Inside this method I want to load some text files, sometimes big ones, and perform some operations. Since this text files take some time to load, I would like to load them in a different thread and perform some alternative operations while waiting for them to be ready. In this thread I would like to call another class' method to load the files.

I have created the following struct:

```
struct args {
   int cmd;
   Class2 * object2;
}
```

This is the structure of `Class1::Run`:

```
pthread load_thread;
struct args thread_args;
thread_args.cmd = 0; //this is used to specify the kind of file to be loaded
thread_args.object2 = object2;
pthread_create( &load_thread, NULL, &ThreadHelper, (void*) &thread_args );
```

`object2` has been declared in `Class1` as `Class2 * object2` and initialized somewhere else.

The `ThreadHelper` function has been declared as `static` inside `Class1` and it is structured as follows:

```
void * Class1::ThreadHelper(void * thread_args) {
   struct args * targs = (struct args*) thread_args;
   targs->object2->LoadFile(targs->cmd);
}
```

All this is causing a segmentation fault. How can I solve?
Also, since the Run function runs sequentially, could it be a problem if a new thread is created before the next one has finished?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you pass to thread a pointer to local variable `thread_args`. You should make it either global variable - move it outside function, or allocate it on heap, i.e.:

```
pthread load_thread;
struct args* thread_args=new args;
thread_args->cmd = 0; //this is used to specify the kind of file to be loaded
thread_args->object2 = object2;
pthread_create( &load_thread, NULL, &ThreadHelper, (void*) thread_args );
```

and dont forget to delete it inside thread function after you are done with its work (you may use std::unique_ptr to make it automatic).

---

now I see you could move `struct args thread_args;` to `Class1` - same as `object2`.

Comment: I've tried the second thing, but it still gives me the same. I'll try the first solution now

Comment: @charles as for the second suggestion: make sure `Class1` instance which holds `thread_args` will not be destroyed before your thread finishes.